# from airflow.providers.amazon.transfers.local_to_s3 import LocalToS3Operator ModuleNotFoundError: No module 'airflow.providers.amazon.transfers'

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-api

actually my dag file count increases but dag file not shows on dag file list and broken dag: module not found error but I install required packages..but still got an error,what can I do?

I installed requred packages but still got error ..so let me know where I was wrong thats why it shows problem...and how I resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*airflow.providers.amazon.transfers* is incorrect package path

*LocalToS3Operator* is incorrect class name

If you use the latest (v8.17.0 at that moment) [Amazon Provider](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/8.17.0/index.html) you should use this import

```py
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.transfers.local_to_s3 import LocalFilesystemToS3Operator
```